# Angularjs - find element with dynamic classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm adding classes using ng-class, but when I try to find these elements using directive, I'm not able to find them.

```
.factory('loadTemplate', function($compile) {
  return function(template) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: template,
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        console.log(el.find('.step.disabled'));
      }
    }
  }
})

.directive('step1', function(loadTemplate) {
  return loadTemplate('processes/steps/step1.html');
})
```

But it doesn't find the elements (Chrome console output):

```
context: div
length: 0
prevObject: o.fn.init[1]
selector: ".step.disabled"
__proto__: Object[0]
```

processes/steps/step1.html:

```
<div>
  <div toggle-box>
    <div class="step" ng-class="{enabled: condition, disabled: !condition}">
...
```

And I'm sure that there are .disabled divs.

When I try finding the elements using only $('.step'), I can find them, because the class is already there.

How can I solve this?

Here is a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/AFYMqLx0wP3tRFFWrADd?p=preview

Comment: `angular.element` only supports tags as arguments to `find` (since it uses jqLite). If jQuery is available to you, use its selection syntax instead to reach what you need.

Comment: I'm using jQuery, I added a Plunker with code example and README. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was to wait for Angular to finish rendering the view, wrapping with a $timeout function even with a 0 timeout it will work. Like this:

Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/rCqyc4AiPNLq1WtpaHJp?p=preview

```
.factory('loadTemplate', function($timeout) {
  return function(template) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: template,
      link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
        $timeout(function() {
          $('.step.disabled').attr('border-color', '#f00');
        }, 0);
      }
    }
  }
})

.directive('step1', function(loadTemplate) {
  return loadTemplate('processes/steps/step1.html');
})
```